# Should I use JayData in MVC 4 with WebApi and OData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odata, asp.net-web-api, jaydata

My manager told me to do research on jaydata as dataservice for performing CRUD operations. I am exploring jaydata from last two weeks.

My requirement is that I have WebApi Controllers at server which will accept all requests for performing CRUD operations. For filtering, I will used OData.

In my case, only WebApi provider is helpful. I thought 'OData' provider will wrok but it requires metadata from server and I don't have any service to provide those metadata.

Any example or documentation I have seen so far are not related to WebApi in JayData site. Even they use some kind of Context paradigm which is not applicable for WebApi.

What should I do? 
Any advice? 
Should I use JayData in my project?

Answer (score 0):

This is the article you are looking for - http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-use-jaydata-with-asp.net-web-api---i

You shouldn't worry about the metadata as you can build the necessary JavaScript data model manually.